# Comparing two different sentences having same meaning in Excel

Tags: excel, data-analysis

I have two cells.

```
Cell 1 contains this value --> Portfolio Rule Failure (Justification Required):  Style Sector Structure:     0.93% for MUNI - SENIOR LIVING breaks the 0.00% maximum failure limit.  Style Min Security Rating: NR breaks the BBB- minimum failure limit. 

Cell 2 contains this value --> Hard Rule Failure   (Requires Portfolio Rule Justification to override):  Sector Max Weight % - Style failed: MUNI - SENIOR LIVING: 0.93%   Min None   Max 0%  Min Security Rating - Style failed: Worse Than BBB-: 0.93%   Min None   Max 0%
```

If you read, both depicts the same meaning. If i try to compare both these in excel, it will say that both are different. But actually they have same meaning though the words used are different. Is there a way in excel or some data analysis tools to say that both are same?

One way to replace the similar pattern words in one of the columns with the other, but I have 1000s of records like this, hence it might be nearly impossible to update these manually.

Please advice.

Comment: You can break sentences into words, remove whitespace, punctuation, and capitalization; then you can compare how similar they are by word content. 

But this isn't really enough to process natural language. Compare: "this soup is good", "this is soup is very good", and "this soup is not good". Based on edit distance or word composition, you can't tell which of those are the same. 

With a much larger corpus of text you could try various [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) methods, but it would be a nightmare to code in VBA.

Comment: @arvi1000 - thank you very much for the nice explaination

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach you might try: If you can get the complete inventory of all possible messages or message patterns into a dedicated worksheet and do the identification of duplicates there,  and provide a standard definition then use vlookup to grab that standard

essentially you build a dictionary that serves to interpret the messages once, and then refer to it as needed.

You may need to parse the original message into logical pieces like 
Message type eg hard failure, warning, etc

Attribute that triggered the message eg MUNI - SENIOR LIVING

Reason, eg failure limit exceeded